# How to get react leaflet marker latlng when moving it?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to get latlng of my marker, after I move it, because in future I will set up fixed markers, and I need to get accurate positions for them, using temporary marker, move it and check it's position. But since my whole component is a class, I cannot use most things I looked up online. For now it just displays map center coordinates. Also, I thought of using RxJS but I have no idea how to check like "move" marker event and send it's position to a paragraph.

```
<p style={{ color: "white" }}>
    latitude: {position.lat}, longitude: {position.lng}{" "}
</p>
```

Here is the code

```
https://pastebin.com/wEgkNaf1
```

Comment: https://tomik23.github.io/react-leaflet-examples/#/dragable-markers

Comment: nice, how did I not see that. I found another solution by that time but thanks!